# My Date Range in Oracle 10g is not Working

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

This looks a very silly question but i am stuck in this
i have tried multiple formats , I have used >= and <=  and also used between but nothing is working for me.

The question is when i run this query it give me 4 records

```
      SELECT * FROM OBS_MEDICATIONS
      WHERE START_DATE IS NOT NULL
      AND trunc(START_DATE) >= TO_DATE('02-01-2022','MM-DD-YYYY')
```

But when i run this it give me nothing

```
       SELECT * FROM OBS_MEDICATIONS
       WHERE START_DATE IS NOT NULL
       AND trunc(START_DATE) <= TO_DATE('02-10-2022','MM-DD-YYYY')
```

Also when i run this it also give nothing because less equal to not working somehow.

```
       SELECT * FROM OBS_MEDICATIONS
       WHERE START_DATE IS NOT NULL
       AND trunc(START_DATE) >= TO_DATE('02-01-2022','MM-DD-YYYY')
       AND  trunc(START_DATE) <= TO_DATE('02-10-2022','MM-DD-YYYY')
```

Comment: It sounds like you just have those four dates after February 10th? What start date values does the first query show? (At a guess you're confusing Feb 10th with Oct 2nd - using an unambiguous format like YYYY-MM-DD might help.) If not... what data type is that column; and what do you get if you change `select *` to `select to_char(start_date, 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` and to `select dump(start_date)`? (Please add those queries and results to the question, not as comments).

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table (a minimal example removing any irrelevant columns); the `INSERT` statements for your sample data; and the expected output. The simplest answer may be that there are values that are after 10th February that the first query sees that are excluded from the second and third queries.